# TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float while loading .npy file

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, matplotlib

I want to load .npy file in Anaconda3 Prompt.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img_array = np.load.('delta1.npy',encoding = 'latin1')
plt.imshow(img_array,cmap = "gray")
plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check1.py", line 12, in <module>
    plt.imshow(img_array,cmap = "gray")
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2699, in imshow
    None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5494, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 634, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

I want to know exactly what mistake I did that I got the error above.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try to convert your array to Image : `from PIL import Image` `img = Image.fromarray(img_array)`, then `plt.imshow(img, cmap = "gray")`

Comment: Take a close look at ‚img_array‘. What does the data look like? What is its shape and dtype?

Comment: Please share your file `delta1.npy`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your numpy array to an Image format to be able to `plt.imshow()` it.

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(img_array)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = "gray")
```

[source](https://kite.com/python/examples/4887/pil-convert-between-a-pil-%60image%60-and-a-numpy-%60array%60)